# Best way to convert object to document and back?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript

Currently all my objects that I need to store have a constructor taking a corresponding document, and a function that creates a document out of the object. However, it turns out that it's quite a lot of work, and every time I add a new property I have to add it to the object, the constructor, the function creating a document, and the schema. Is there a way to optimize this, so I only have to add the property in one place?

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is [serialisation](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson). However, I think to help you further you'll have to post some code.

Comment: This looks promising. Is it still possible to query for attributes this way, or do I have to store the attributes as usual if I want to query for them?